# Split "/" with complex conditions in JQ

Tags: jq

I have json:

```json
    "spec": {
        "background": true,
        "failurePolicy": "Fail",
        "rules": [
            {
                "exclude": {
                    "resources": {}
                },
                "generate": {
                    "clone": {}
                },
                "match": {
                    "resources": {
                        "kinds": [
                            "networking.k8s.io/v1/NetworkPolicy"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "mutate": {},
                "name": "validate-nodeport",
                "validate": {
                    "message": "Services of type NodePort are not allowed.",
                    "pattern": {
                        "spec": {
                            "type": "!NodePort"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "validationFailureAction": "audit"
    },
    "status": {
        "ready": true
    }
}
```

I need to parse this string `"networking.k8s.io/v1/NetworkPolicy"`, BUT its can be looks like `Kind` or `Version/Kind` or `Version/Group/Kind`. I have jq command only for `Kind` case: `.spec.rules[0].match.resources.kinds[] as $kind`

I need more universal command for split string to "/", but in some cases there may be one "/" and in some cases two. I need to parse it correctly and write a command with the condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split up a string into an array using the `/` operator and a separator, `"/"` in your case:

```
.spec.rules[0].match.resources.kinds / "/"
```

```json
[
  "networking.k8s.io",
  "v1",
  "NetworkPolicy"
]
```

Then, rearrange according to the presence of the elements:

```
... | [select(.[1])[0] // null, select(.[2])[1] // null, last]
```

Finally, assign the array elements to multiple variables at once:

```
... as [$version,$group,$kind]
```

Combined:

```
(.spec.rules[0].match.resources.kinds / "/")
| [select(.[1])[0] // null, select(.[2])[1] // null, last]
  as [$version,$group,$kind]
| {$version,$group,$kind}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vAgo6WI-44)

Comment: I need parse it like $ver, $gr, $kind, when for example version or group not be define